# Looping through the table dynamically in lua

Tags: object, lua

In the below code I am trying to do pattern match between pathstr and arr.

> Example - According to pathstr "/sample/find/apples/red", if red and apples is found in arr table then I will set the
>   flag value to true and break the loop.

Currently I have hard coded v[2] in loop. How can I avoid that and dynamically check the values in table

```
function ContainsWholeWord(input, word)
    return string.find(input, "%f[%w]" .. word .. "%f[%W]")
end
local pathstr = "/sample/find/fruits/Apple/red"
local flag = false
local arr =
{
  fruits = {Apple={price=10,color=red}},
  vegetables = { Beans={price=10,color=red}}
}
for k, v in pairs(arr) do
    //call ContainsWholeWord function and match pattern of table in pathstr.     
If found, set flag value
        flag = true
        print(flag)
        break
        end
    end
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/s4mvOF)

Comment: For the example code I don't understand what _dynamic_ would mean as you clearly _need_ to access a specific index of v in the code. Do you mean that "red" would be a table of strings to search from the pathstr? Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I'm confused, can you give us a simpler example which still demonstrates your problem? It'll be easier for us, and you will learn a lot more.

Comment: @warspyking;@Rochet2 I need to check whether the "fruits/Apple/red" words are found in arr table. How can i achieve this

Comment: Ah I see now. ```if type(arr.fruits) == "table" and type(arr.fruits.apple) == "table" and fruits.apple.color == "red" then``` does this work in your case? If so I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a key-value:

```
local arr = {
    apples = { code="a", color="red", amount=5 },
    oranges = { code="o", color="orange", amount=12 },
    pears = { code="p", color="green", amount=7 },
}
```

and then

```
ContainsWholeWord(pathstr, v.color)
```